# How to get villagers to like me again after killing their livestock?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I accidentally killed a chicken, and now people hate me. How do I get them to like me again?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Leave the area for **3** ingame days. If you return, people will like you again.

Equally, find a guard and sheath your weapon. Then go to prison or pay your bounty.

Comment: Don't you mean “unsheath”?  Well, 5 years later, and if nobody cared then . . .

Comment: No he meant Sheath. Find a guard and put your weapon away when he comes at you. If you are not holding a weapon you will need to pull one out and put it away again. This will usually cause the guard to stop attacking you and offer to arrest you instead. Of course if you attack the guard before putting your weapon away it may not work.

Answer (score 3):

Get away from the place, into the wilderness, and wait 3 days before returning.

Answer (score 1):

Well how many people saw? If the whole village saw, yield to the guards. If only a few people saw kill them and your bounty is gone. For example when I killed the last witness of my crime (I attacked Thalmor and farmers), a bounty worth 4000 was removed from Whiterun.

Alternatively, if you're playing on PC; look up codes to remove bounty. Also you could just kill everyone in the village. Unless some are essential, but there shouldn't be any if you finished the main quest.

Answer (score 0):

Load a save from before you killed the chicken and everything will be fine.