# Skyrim - Killed a chicken in the first town, how screwed is my game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the people of a village like me again after killing their livestock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35634/how-to-get-the-people-of-a-village-like-me-again-after-killing-their-livestock)

So I just started playing Skyrim, and I got to the first town with the mission to talk to Alvor.  I also happened to decide that it would make sense to practice my archery skills on one of the chickens that was wandering along the city streets.

Apparently this is a big no-no, because the next thing I knew some old peasant dude was coming at me with an axe.  I ran outside of city limits, but the guy chased after me so I killed him.  Then when I went back into the town a guard and a couple of other NPC's attacked me.  I put them down as well and went about my business.  I went into the shop and found the shopkeeper was not hostile to me, and assumed that meant that everything was fine.

I did the golden claw quest and got the word of power or whatever it was.  Went back to the shopkeeper and got my reward, then decided it was a good time to talk to Alvor.  Unfortunately as soon as I step into his house his wife starts attacking me.  I can kill her, but then of course Alvor isn't much in the mood for talking.

So anyways, how screwed up is my game?  Is Alvor a major character as far as the plot matters, or can I just kill him and get on with things?  If he is a major character, is there any way to recover at this point apart from loading an old save?  If I leave town for a bit will they forget that I killed a chicken (and then all the people who rushed to avenge the chicken) and talk to me again?

Comment: You killed the sacred chicken. Now you will burn for your sins!

Comment: Voted up because of epic tittle and epic story !

Comment: Loved the story, voted to reopen for the first two questions: " Is Alvor a major character as far as the plot matters, or can I just kill him and get on with things? If he is a major character, is there any way to recover at this point apart from loading an old save?"

Comment: [Relevant](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFIZfuDLEy8)

Comment: there are not suppose to be any guards in Riverwood until you do some quests.

Comment: Spoiler: Alvor is needed for the end boss, your game is screwed :(. Joking, I don't think he's a major character. Usually the game is smart enough to not let you kill characters that are critical to the story. I've noticed that when I 'killed' someone critical to the plotline, the game would simply tell me they were unconscious. At which point they would of course wake back up and continue attacking me, so in short if he stays dead then I'd say he's not critical to the plotline.